# Splitting the array with / slash

Tags: c#, string, split, delimiter

From debugger in my string of arrays I am getting this:

```
"/mercedes-benz/190-class/1993/" class="canonicalLink" data-qstring="?sub=sedan">1993
```

I wish to split text after each `'/'` and get it in `string[]`, here is my effort:

```
Queue<string> see = new Queue<string>(); //char[] a = {'\n '};
       List<car_facts> car_fact_list = new List<car_facts>();
       string[] car_detail;

       foreach (string s in car)
       {
         
            MatchCollection match = Regex.Matches(s, @"<a href=(.+?)</a>",
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            // Here we check the Match instance.
            foreach(Match mm in match)
            {
                // Finally, we get the Group value and display it.
                string key = mm.Groups[1].Value;
                //key.TrimStart('"');
                //key.Trim('"');
                key.Trim();
                
                // @HERE: I tried with string.Split as well and tried many combinations of separators
                car_detail = Regex.Split(key, "//");
                
                see.Enqueue(key);
            }
}
```

In `car_detail[0]` I get this `"$[link]">$[title]`

**from this string**:

```
"/mercedes-benz/190-class/1993/" class="canonicalLink" data-qstring="?sub=sedan">1993
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not clear why you're using a double slash here...

```
string[] details = key.Split('/');
```

should work fine. (Note that forward-slashes *don't* have to be escaped in C#.) For example:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string text = "/mercedes-benz/190-class/1993/";
        string[] bits = text.Split('/');
        foreach (string bit in bits)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", bit);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
''
'mercedes-benz'
'190-class'
'1993'
''
```

The empty strings are due to the leading and trailing slashes. If you want to avoid those, you can use

```
string[] details = key.Split(new[] {'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Notes:

- `car_facts` is a highly unconventional name in C#. Normally you'd have something like `CarFacts` (or potentially just `Car`, `CarInfo` etc). Likewise `car_fact_list` would normally be `carFactList` or something similar.
- This code doesn't do what you expect it to:

  ```
  key.Trim();
  ```

  Strings are immutable in .NET - so `Trim()` returns a reference to a *new* string rather than changing the contents of the existing one. You may want:

  ```
  key = key.Trim();
  ```
- You're currently assigning a value to `car_detail` but never using it. Why?
- Parsing HTML using regular expressions is a really bad idea in general. Consider using [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) or something similar.

Comment: @RobustRob: It certainly *will* work - I'll give a short but complete example. Please give more information than "its not working" (sic). What does it do, compared with what you expected?

Comment: I am getting the same "$[link]">$[title]  , here is a thing , I am telling you these results from values in debugger , I am using VS 2010 WPF C# app

Comment: @RobustRob: It's not at all clear what you mean by that, but try my short but complete program - it works. I can't see what you're doing in a debugger, but if you post a similar short but complete program demonstrating the problem, I *will* be able to see that. Also read the various notes about your code.

Comment: HTML Agility Pack  has very bad documentation , very less examples