# Splitting strings with slashes in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following types of strings. One with three slashes and one with two:

```
a) filepath = "/F00C/Home/About"

b) filepath = "/Administration/Menus"
```

What I need to do is a function that will allow me to get the values of "home" and "administration" and put into topMenu variable and get the values of "Menus" and "About" and put this into the subMenu variable.

I am familiar with the function slashes = filePath.Split('/');  but my situation is not so simple as there are the two types of variables and in both cases I just need to get the last two words.

Is there a simple way that I could make the Split function work for both without anything to complex?

Comment: have you looked at the `System.IO.Path` utlility class?

Comment: possibly duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673817/splitting-the-array-with-slash

Comment: Same as @Daniel, no point in trying to reinvent this wheel.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: Maybe it's me, but I can't find any method in Path giving the last 2 tokens of a path...

Comment: @digEmAll, you can get first one by GetDirectoryName and second one with GetFileName.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: actually, considering the first example, GetDirectoryName returns "\\F00C\\Home" not "Home"...

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: it works if you call GetFileName on the result, though...

Comment: Path.GetFileName("/F00C/Home/About") will return About. Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(("/F00C/Home/About") will return Home. Just keep calling it recursively to you get the number of levels you want, or it runs out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with something like this ?

```
var splits = filePath.Split('/');
var secondLast = splits[splits.Length-2];
var last = splits[splits.Length-1];
```

Remarks:

- Any check on the length of splits array (that must be >= 2) is missing.
- Also, this code works only with forward-slash (`'/'`). To support both backslash and forward-slash separators, have a look at [@Saeed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10387355/316644)

Comment: It will fall over with index out of bounds for invalid input. Well you asked. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var items = filePath.Split('/');
first = items[items.Length - 2];
second = items[items.Length - 1];
```

Also if this is a actual path you can use [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
dir  = Path.GetFileName(dir);
var file = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
```

**Edit:** I edited Path version as the way discussed my digEmAll.

Comment: But then how can I put these items into two variables named topMenu and subMenu?

Comment: @MarieJ, I thought you just want to get one before last one see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Am I'm missing something or you just want:

```
var split = filepath.Split('/');
var last = split[split.Length -1];
var prev = split[split.Length -2];
```