# MVC Get ID from ReturnURL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, query-string

I am building an MVC 4 web application and whenever a user attempts to access a secure page without being authenticated I fire them to the login screen

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
   ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
   return View();
}
```

Once they login, I use the returnURL string to fire them back to the page they previously wanted to access. All good.

However, I was wondering, is there anyway of getting the ID parameter from the returnURL string, e.g., if the returnURL string was

> /Course/ICT/4

is there anyway of just getting the value 4?

Comment: Don't know about any built in methods but you could use  int found = returnUrl.LastIndexOf('/') and then use the returned value with returnUrl.SubString(found) if found is > -1

Comment: @Nate At the moment, I have just been passing the full returnURL, which is of no use to me. I had thought of trimming the string with Left or Right, but again this doesn't seem like the way to do this, mainly because the Parameter could be 4, or 44, or even 4444, therefore it would be hard to know much many characters to trim. Kind of stumped with this one!

Comment: I just posted an answer that should cover most cases of an MVC uri with ID parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to user2025312 and this post [Splitting the array with / slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673817/splitting-the-array-with-slash)

I was able to get the answer

```
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl) 
{
    string[] myString = returnUrl.Split('/');

    var ID = myString[3];

    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = ID;

    return View(); 
}
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could Split the string by "/" into an array and then get the last element in the array.

```
string[] splitURL = returnURL.Split('/');
string id = splitURL[splitURL.Length - 1];
```

And so on. Hope this is of some use.

Comment: Add code sample to parse a potential number into an ind - say Int.TryParse or something.

Answer (score 1):

You might also use a regex like this

```
[^/]+$
```

In your controller like so

```
var id = 0;
int.TryParse(Regex.Match(urnUrl, "[^/]+$"), out id);
```

---

**Edit**

---

Obviously, this answer assumes that you will **not** have a Uri of the following form:

```
/Controller/Action/?id=783
```

Which would render the above method (and the other methods posted) in adequate. In order to support this as well, you will need to do some exception handling.

```
var id = 0;
var afterSlash = Regex.Match(returnUrl, "[^/]+$");
if(int.TryParse(afterSlash, out id) == false)
{
    if(int.TryParse(Regex.Match(afterSlash, "[^=]+$"), out id) == false)
    {
        // probably not a valid uri
    }
}
```

This is probably a good start, but you may need to do more testing and make modifications based on your environment.