# Return value between two characters?

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

If we use the example string:

```
localhost:12345/MATCH_THIS_PART/more_strings
```

How would I return the value `MATCH_THIS_PART` and set it as the value of `returnString`. I think the problem can be solved using regex, and this is what I think would work:

```
string returnString = Regex.Match(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString(), @"not sure what goes here");
```

So basically, what goes in the part where I put

> "not sure what goes here"

Comment: Split with `/` and get the `[1]` element. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673817/splitting-the-array-with-slash)

Answer (score 0):

There are several options. String splitting is the easiest one:

```
string part = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString().Split('/')[1]; // gets the second item
```

Or use this regular expression and get the first capture:

```
.*?\/(.*?)\/.*
```